# SQL Server table exhausting Integer range

Tags: sql-server, database

We have an SQL Server database tables that are running out of ids soon (the primary id is a 32-bit integer and the max id is already about 2 billion). What is the best way to fix this issue?

Multiple attributes (3) in a table have Sequential ID and the range is expected to get exhausted soon

Alter the id type to 64-bit is an option but that would bring down the database for too long because the table has billion of rows.

Comment: Without having to change the key values completely (which would surely break any FKs you may have), I don't see what else to do but to change to a `BIGINT`

Comment: There isn't a "simple" solution. The range of numbers you can store in an `int`, however, isn't 2 billion, it's over 4 billion; -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647). Though you *could* (when the seed gets close to 2^31-1) reset the seed to -2^31, giving you another 2 billion~ rows, if your ID column is also your `CLUSTERED INDEX` that isn't going to be a good idea either; any new data would have to all be put "prior" to the existing data in the index which could get expensive. Changing the data type is the best long term solution, but you'll need to schedule downtime.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for the input. Can we do that without downtime?

Comment: Can you do *what* without downtime?

Comment: And we have application dependency as well, multiple teams are also using this DataBase and we are not aware of their implementation of using those fields

Comment: @Larnu upgrading to bigInt datatype

Comment: I explicitly said you *need* downtime to do that, @Rossy ... *"Changing the data type is the best long term solution, but you'll need to schedule downtime."*

Comment: @Larnu This is what we are trying to solve here and that was the actual ask of this question. I hope you get my point. I saw what you have clearly mentioned **Changing the data type is the best long term solution, but you'll need to schedule downtime.** But we are searching for alternate approch. Thanks for your time.

Comment: *"But we are searching for alternate approch"* Which is why I mentioned resetting the seed as well... But that isn't a *good* solution; at best it's a work around and *will* have performance implications as I highlighted. There is no "magic button"; the *real;* solution is schedule downtime and solve the data type.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid downtime for this kind of change. You may also have a bigger problem than you realize... if this is a primary key column that suggests that one or more tables will have foreign key columns referencing it. You need to change the data types of those foreign key columns as well.

Comment: What about creating a new table with BigInt, and copying the data to a new table in short batches (since we have ~1 year before numbers get over). And slowly switching to the new table. what is your opinion

Comment: @Rossy No one but you knows exactly how your table is used. Your goal is very much dependent on how rows are added, updated or deleted. And, as already mentioned, you need to determine if there are any dependencies on this table. Those are things you do now as a part of your research. Once you understand the **full scope** of your issue, you can then decided on a path. Reseeding an identity column is a easy way to double the range - but coders often use logic based on an identity value > 0.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on? I ask because in SQL 2016, they introduced online alter column. So you may be able to do `alter table yourTable alter column yourColumn bigint not null with (online = on)`.